# Flask-Mongoengine always connects to `test` database

Tags: flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I am using flask together with flask-mongoengine. The application is set up via an application factory as described [here](https://hackersandslackers.com/flask-application-factory/).

My models are defined in separate files, as follows:

```
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
db = MongoEngine()

class NodeModel(db.Document):
    node_id = db.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    ....
```

The application factory in `__init__.py` looks as follows:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path=''
    ...
    app.config['MONGODB_DB'] = 'myDb'
    app.config['MONGODB_HOST'] = ....
    app.config['MONGODB_UUIDREPRESENTATION'] = 'standard'

    with app.app_context():
        from models import db
        db.init_app(app)
        ...
    
    return app
```

The application fires up correctly, all routes are working. However, data is stored in the default `test` database, not in `myDb`. Other MongoDB configurations, like the host and `MONGODB_UUIDREPRESENTATION` are respected. I have been researching this problem for several hours now, but to no avail. What am I missing? How do I set up flask-mongoengine to connect with the correct database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it help if you do it through `app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS']`?
e.g.

```
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
    'db': 'myDb',
    'host': os.getenv('MONGODB_HOST', 'localhost:27017'),
}
```

Also, mind that database name from uri has priority over name. So if you use

```
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
    'db': 'myDb',
    'host': 'mongodb://localhost/',
    ...
}
```

mongoengine will write to the `test` db, because there's none set in host.

By the way, I *think* mongoengine doesn't always pick up on db name in the URI, because when I recently used this

```
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
    'host': 'mongodb://localhost/myDb',
    ...
}
```

mongoengine kept writing to `test` as well.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the host string overrides the explicit DB setting. Thanks for that hint!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. When you get the connection string from Azure  portal, it looks like this.

```
export MONGODBCONNSTR="mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<HOST>:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb&retrywrites=false&maxIdleTimeMS=120000&appName=@cpe-self-service-db@"
```

Adding my database name 'MYDB' to this connection in the URI as below.

```
export MONGODBCONNSTR="mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<HOST>:10255/MYDB?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb&retrywrites=false&maxIdleTimeMS=120000&appName=@cpe-self-service-db@"
```

Then I have update from

```
 app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
    'host': f'{os.environ.get("MONGODBCONNSTR")}/MYDB'
}
```

TO

```
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {  
        'host': f'{os.environ.get("MONGODBCONNSTR")}'  
    }
```

**OR**

```
app.config['MONGODB_HOST'] = f'{os.environ.get("MONGODBCONNSTR")}'
```

It worked for me.